# Finblog from Sci-fi book and movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, novel

What book and movie is the character Finblog from? They only say "Finblog", and all the other Finblogs know another Finblog's name but they don't say it around outsiders. In the book and movie there are humans, a cyborg and arachnid chick that travel underground through various tunnels to escape. While down there the arachnid bangs the cyborg.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Was this in English that you watched/read it? And are you certain this was both a book and a movie?

Comment: Is chick a term for a young arachnid? And why would it hit the cybord? Did it attack the cybord, did it need to make a loud sound and hit it's metal parts? I find much of this question confusing.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: On the off chance you're serious, I think they're using slang. They're saying that an arachnid female has sex with a cyborg (of indeterminate gender, I suppose) in the tunnels.

Answer (score 1):

This is Phillip Jose Farmer's **The Dungeon**, a series of six books, none of which was written by Farmer. I don't think it was a movie though.

See if this link brings back memories:

http://plaidspots.plaidscape.net/2008/12/phillip-jose-farmers-the-dungeon/

Finbogg is the character you're thinking of. There's also a giant, sentient, telepathic spider called Shriek and a cyborg, Chang Guafe.

At one point in one of the books, Shriek enters a sort of mating heat where the urge builds up in her to mate with, and kill, a male spider. Chang Guafe, being a cyborg, is the only one of the party strong enough to manually help her out and not be killed by her.